# Javascript with AJAX

Tags: ajax

am passing a varible from javascript using ajax to PHP action.But that does not work at all.

```
function approve(id) {
    var idemail = id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/feedback/public/index/approve/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "idemail=" + idemail,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Approved successfully')
        }
    })
```

In PHP action

```
public function approveAction() {
    $approvemail = $_POST['idemail'];
    echo $approvemail;
}
```

But there is no success response and no echo email also.Please help me.

Comment: http://localhost/feedback/public/index/approve/... what's the actual .php file?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on your JavaScript function definition, is that a typo in the question or is it missing in your actual code too? That `$.ajax()` function is a jQuery function - have you included jQuery in your page? And, finally, you haven't provided any information on how that function is actually called.

Comment: Are you sure the url is good? There is no filename at the end of your url... try putting the php filename after it. ex: http://localhost/feedback/public/index/approve/index.php . and see if you get a response.

Comment: Hi,No it is typo in the question.It is correct in code.@Jozzeh,it is my action in the controller http://localhost/feedback/public/index/approve/index.php,also not working

Comment: @Idsaru seems like you're using a framework; so shouldn't the request be like `server/app/controller/actionName`?? also please check if the url is directly accessible through the browser!

Comment: @Vishal.Can you suggest me wat would be the better way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is correct. It seems the url you are calling isn't understanding the ajax call. Can you check if your application module handles normal and ajax url in different ways. maybe you can try calling simple test url like `http://localhost/test.php` and check if that works.